# How to implement Google maps API via <iFrame>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I'm trying to implement the Google maps API using the iframe tag in my Rails project so when a user looks up an event they can see where it's located.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=“+<%= addrees %>+”&key="APIKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and this is how I'm calling it in my controller:

```
@organizations = @organization.address
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `address' for #<Organization:0x007ff10d44e9d0>
```

I feel like I'm calling it wrong in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@organization.address` instead of `address` and you need pass your APIKEY to set a key param:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?<%= {q: @organization.address, key: 'APIKEY'}.to_query %>" 
 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: do you mean changing it like this?  <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?<%= {q: @organization.address, key: 'APIKEY'}.to_query %>" 
 allowfullscreen></iframe> ..  just tried that and got hit with the same error!

Comment: Do you have `address` field in organizations table?

Comment: no I don't, I have name, description and location in my organizations table.

Comment: So, you have to create an address field. Just for testing you can create method address in an organization model and return a real address. `def address; "Houston";end`

Comment: can I use it with my location field or do I have to add in an address field into my schema again?

Comment: Of course, use `location` field instead of `address`

Comment: I just added that line of code. I have my website working but now I have an error from my local host say "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrganizationsController#show
Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=allowfullscreen" where the box for my map should be

Comment: hey I actually got it to work but now I have the following error on my organizations.show page: The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This service requires an API key. with this line of code    <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=“+<%= @organization.location %>+”&key=YOUR KEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>  i've tried requesting a new key a few times but all are not working is htere another reason as to why that would happen?

Comment: Have you enabled maps api in google developer console?

Comment: yeah i did do that

Comment: hey!! I figured it out . I had an extra q somewhere. Thank you so much for helping me troubleshoot!

Comment: `<%= ` of course! so simple :-)